# Problems with paginate function laravel 4

Tags: laravel, paginator

I need to get the results of the laravel paginator but seems is not working, im trying to do this query

```
$products = DB::table('Products')->paginate(5);
```

When i try to print the query result, doesn't show me the result, instead show me the whole Paginator Laravel Class and other nasty stuff.

Here is the ouput example that i have now

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506086/

Comment: what do you have in your view?  and how are you passing `$products` to the view from the Controller?

Comment: Im trying to paginate the results with angular, with php (laravel) i have now one function that return a JSONP object and that should contain the records paginated, i mean

    $products = DB::table('Products')->paginate(5);

I figure out that query should return me the first 5 record or am i wrong with that?

Comment: ok.. can you share some more code?  the relevant bits from your view and controller for example?

Comment: Controller: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506211/
View: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506219/
Angular: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7506224/

the <% %> is the replacement for the angular tags, blade conflict you know.



Thanks :)

Comment: ah, you might run into trouble combining it with Angular like this.. Might be easier to roll your own pagination with a limited query: `$products = DB::table('products')->skip(page*5)->take(5)->get();`

Comment: That's what i thought now, here is my solution:

    $currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1;
    $pagedData = array_slice($products, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
    $matches = Paginator::make($pagedData, count($products), $perPage);

thanks @msturdy

Comment: glad to help.. don't forget to add that as an answer so that the next poor soul who has the problem can see it :)

Comment: My reputation dont leave me to answer my question, please you answer, anyway you give me the clue to get my solution :) @msturdy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are combining it with Angular you might want to consider using [limited queries](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects) instead of Laravel's `Paginator`, as all you need to do is return a selection of items from the DB.

For example, in your Controller (and this is very simplified):

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $currentPage = (int)Input::get('page') - 1;

    $products = DB::table('products')->skip(currentPage*5)
                                     ->take(5)
                                     ->get();

    return Response::json($products);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
$products = DB::table('Products')->paginate(5);
```

You'll get an `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` object and this will contain `data` array with other properties and methods. If you pass `$users` to the `view` then in your `view` you can loop the `$users` to print out user models and finally you can print out pagination links.

For example:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->username }}
    {{ $product->email }}
@endforeach;

{{ $products->links() }}
```

To print out the query result you may try this:

```
$products->getItems();
```

If you want to pass the result as `json` to your client `side/js` then you may try this:

```
return $products; // it'll be a json string
```

In the client side you'll get something like this when parsed to an object:

```
Object {total: 10, per_page: 5, current_page: 1, last_page: 2, from: 1…}
current_page: 1
data: Array[5]
from: 1
last_page: 2
per_page: 5
to: 5
total: 10
__proto__: Object
```

To access the data you may use something like this:

```
yourObject.data; // or yourObject['data'];
```

This will be an array of objects (models).